# Why I am unable to change the QR Code's size in iText7?

Tags: itext7

How to change QR Code size?

```
            using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader _pdf_reader = 
                new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader("tmp/example.pdf"))
            {
                using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(_pdf_reader, new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter("tmp/output.pdf").SetSmartMode(true)))
                {
                    BarcodeQRCode qrc = new BarcodeQRCode("https://google.com");

                    PdfFormXObject xObject = qrc.CreateFormXObject(ColorConstants.BLACK, pdfDoc);

                    float _w = pdfDoc.GetPage(1).GetPageSize().GetWidth();
                    float _h = pdfDoc.GetPage(1).GetPageSize().GetHeight();
                    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.GetPage(1));
                    canvas.SaveState();
                    canvas.SetFillColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    //canvas.Rectangle(_w - 90, _h - 90, 100, 100);
                    canvas.Fill();
                    canvas.RestoreState();
                    canvas.AddXObject(xObject, _w - qrc.GetBarcodeSize().GetWidth(), _h - qrc.GetBarcodeSize().GetHeight());
                }
            }
```

I try:

```
 qrc.GetBarcodeSize().GetHeight();
 qrc.GetBarcodeSize().GetWidth();
```

it returns 33

I try to set Height & Width to 100 like below:

```
 qrc.GetBarcodeSize().SetHeight(100);
 qrc.GetBarcodeSize().SetWidth(100);
```

and then check the size again, but it keeps returning 33, is it a bug? or Did I miss something?

please help

thanks
Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try to set Height & Width to 100 like below:

Actually, you can`t change the QrCode side this way.
In fact, QRcode is an n*n grid where n depends on some parameters as a QR code version and the error correction level. 
When generating, iText uses the smallest version that can fit the content. This is version 4 (33*33) in your case.

The easiest way to change the size of QrCode in a document is by using the version of the `createFormXObject` method which accepts the `moduleSide` parameter.

```
float moduleSize = 100/qrc.GetBarcodeSize().GetHeight();    
qrc.createFormXObject(foreground, moduleSize, document)
```

Module size here is size of the barcode`s grid cell (1 by default).

Answer (score 0):

iTxt 7 Qrcode size effected by three parameter in hints, example example for your reference.

```
//C# code
//Prepare all necessary properties to create the qrcode
IDictionary<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = new Dictionary<EncodeHintType, object>();

//default character set (ISO-8859-1)
hints[EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET] = "UTF-8";

//Qrcode Error correction level L,M,Q,H
//default ErrorCorrectionLevel.L
hints[EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION] = ErrorCorrectionLevel.L;

//Qrcode minimal version level
//default 4
hints[EncodeHintType.MIN_VERSION_NR] = 6;

string code = "Qrcode content here";
BarcodeQRCode qrcode = new BarcodeQRCode(code, hints);
```